# Update fragment UIs after in-app purchase on android

Tags: android, android-fragments, in-app-purchase

I have a activity with multiple fragments that change based on the user events. Out of these fragments three have inapp purchases. For instance if they haven't purchased the feature, lock icon will be shown. After user purchases I want to change the fragment UI and icons. Using following method on main activity, I can get variables, but How can I update the fragments from main activity upon purchase completion.

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
```

Answer (score 0):

In any way.. You could use localbroadcast, otto/eventbus, set data directly from activity to fragment, observer pattern, data-binding.. The whole arsenal of things

Edited: i think [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) will be best approach to use in your case (Of cource you can use fragment manager, but it will be more tricky)

or just subscribe to purchase broadcast with action

```
public static final String ACTION = "com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED"
```

See more in a Billing sample on android developers

Comment: Thanks for your comment, can I use the fragment manager and get the current fragment and execute a method to update the UI, if the current fragment is one that has inapp purchase buttons?